# How to eaisly pass dynamic parameter to a Query (QueryService) in Spartacus?

Tags: spartacus-storefront

At the first sight the Query (QueryService) in Spartacus doesn't seem to accept any dynamic parameters. For instance fetching list of Orders but based on the dynamic parameter `searchPhrase$`.
The workaround is to configure a `reloadOn` event for the Query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamic parameters in Spartacus Query (QueryService). It suffices to use RxJs `swtichMap` for example and switch from your dynamic parameter `searchPhrase$` to the call to the data service (connector). For example:

```
export class CustomOrdersService {
  /* ... */
  protected queryService = inject(QueryService);
  protected searchPhrase$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');

  protected ordersQuery$: Query<Orders[]> = this.queryService.create(() =>
    this.searchPhrase$.pipe(
      switchMap((searchPhrase) => {
        this.connector.getOrders({ searchPhrase }); // loads actual Orders from http
      })
    )
  );

  public setSearchPhrase(searchPhrase: string): void {
    this.searchPhrase$.next(searchPhrase);
  }
  public orders$ = this.ordersQuery$.get();
}
```